# Transform XML to latex using python

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to insert text at starting and ending of the element in XML using python

Or any config files to insert the text using python

eg:
Input:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>
        or <a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>
        or linktag{<a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a>}.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('index.html')  
root = tree.getroot()  
  
for val in root.findall("./book/[price='5.95']"):  
    print(val.attrib)

for elem in root.findall("body/p/a"):   
    elem.tag = "linktag{"

tree.write("output.xhtml")
```

Tried but not getting the expected output

Comment: I need to insert the text like (nested mml tags under mml:math)
Input: <equation><mml:math...........</mml:math><caption>(1.1)</caption></equation>

Output: \Equation{1.1}{<equation><mml:math...........</mml:math><caption>(1.1)</caption></equation>}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` (regular expressions). For instance, you can enclose all links in `linktag{..}` with the following:

```
import re

replace_pattern = re.compile(r"(<a.*?</a>)")

with open("output.html", "w") as fo:
    with open("index.html", 'r') as fi:
        for line in fi:
            fo.write(re.sub(replace_pattern, r"linktag{\1}", line))
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Moved to linktag{<a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>}
        or linktag{<a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a>}.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Beware that this won't work with intricated/nested tags, for which Regular Expression are not appropriate. But since your Output isn't a valid XML/HTML, `ET` won't help you here.